# How to structure a complex array of data

Tags: javascript

I need help understanding the easiest way to create an array which carries 4 pieces of information and a unique ID tied to it.

My goal is to plot 4 numbers plus an ID which is what im trying to retrieve.

Then the second part of my confusion is finding some way to check the 4 numbers and get the ID. But I'm really confused how to make such an array in JS.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of objects and each object has four pieces of data and an id, you would do it like this:

```
var list = [
    {id: "135", data: [9,129,345, 687]},
    {id: "239", data: [596,382,0,687,33467]}
];
```

You would access the data like this:

```
list[0].id
list[0].data[0]
list[0].data[1]
list[0].data.length
```

If you want an object that is indexed by id and each id has four pieces of data associated with it, you'd to it like this:

```
var index = {
    "135": [9,129,345, 687],
    "299": [596,382,0,687,33467]
};
```

You would access this data like this:

```
index["135"][0]
index["135"][1]
index["299"][0]
```

If you know the ids and want to look data up by id, you would use the second form.  If you don't know the ids and just want to be able to easily iterate through the data and see what the ids are and the data is, then you would use the first form.

Comment: so data is sort of an internal array within the list array?

Comment: @Dave - `list` is an array of objects so each element of the array is an object.  Each object has two properties, an `id` and `data`.  The `id` property is a string.  The `data` property is an array of numbers.  I added a second, alternate form of organizing the data depending upon how you want to access it.

Comment: @Dave, I don't understand your question?  I don't declare static elements of arrays by manually assigning them to a specific array index.  I declare multiple initial elements of arrays like I've done in my answer above use a multi-element data declaration `[1,99,456,2]`.

Comment: Yeah i have worked out what you meant now and have since managed to get it to work ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would do it like this:

```
{
     "id": [ "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
}
```

You can construct it like so:

```
var map = {};
map[id] = [ "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
```

Comment: How would you obtain the map[id] with if statements ?

Comment: The same way: `if( map["myid"] ) { console.log(map["myid"]); }` will print out your array.

Comment: I mean- if i'm trying to find "myid" from the 4 data points. If I have 4 numbers I need to check the array and get the relevant id .. or return false if not existent?

Comment: If you want to find something in the array, than you can do `map["myid"] && map["myid"].indexOf(...)`

Comment: but map["myid"] is suggest i already know myid? cos im using a variable?

Answer (score -1):

If you thought about an object with numbers, which every has its own id, you can do also that:

```
var map = {id1:"data1", id2:"data2", id3:"data3", id4:"data4"};

for(x in map) {
    alert(x + ": " + map[x]);
}
```